# Another Easy jQuery Question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the bellow code, I wish to create an IF statement so the loadScript function is only called for a specific HREF. But when I try and alert the value of the href it returns "Undefined"...

Many Thanks, 
J

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.jNav').click(function()
            {
                $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function() 
                {
                    alert("From here " + $(this).attr('href') + " to here.");
                    loadScript();
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: If it's so easy then I guess you know how to do it already!

Comment: Whoa! so many answers in 2 minutes. This must be really easy one as promised by OP :). I stopped writing my answer when I saw '4 new answers have been posted' in the notification bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is just scoping.  In your load() callback, this refers to the element you're calling load() on, which happens to be `$('#sandbox')`, and thus: no href.  Usually what I do is something like this:

```
$('.jNav').click(function()
{
  var self = this;
  $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function() 
  {
    // Notice the use of self here, as we declared above
    alert("From here " + $(self).attr('href') + " to here.");
    loadScript();
  });
  return false;
});
```

Doing this ensures that you can still get to the thing that you clicked from inside the load() callback.

Comment: you can just use `var self = this.href;`

Comment: @aSeptic True dat. However, it's good practice in general to scope the calling object like this, in case you need it for more than just its href.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of context: The call to `$(this)` in the alert refers to `$('#sandbox')` not `$('.jNav')`. Simply define a variable for you first reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inside the callback for `$('#sandbox').load`, `this` refers to `$('#sandbox')`, and not to `$('.jNav')`.  If you want to alert the href, save that (or a reference to `this`) in a variable.

```
$('.jNav').click(function(){
  var that = this;
  $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function(){
    alert($(that).attr('href'));
    //...
  });
}
```

OR

```
$('.jNav').click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function(){
    alert(href);
    //...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` was the `.jNav`, but in your callback it's now the `#sandbox`. Pre-cache the variable at the point where it's presented to you, then use it wherever you like.

Improving slightly on Groovetrain's answer, I'd write:

```
$('.jNav').click(function(event) {
  var $self = $(this);
  var href  = $self.attr('href');

  $('#sandbox').load(href, function() {
    alert("From here " + href + " to here.");
    loadScript();
  });

  event.preventDefault(); // better than `return false`
});
```

Comment: You need to pass `event` into the click function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your innnermost function the context (`this`) is set to the #sandbox element. You'll want to get the href attribute from the .jNav element beforehand and store it in a variable.

[Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/K5xDN/)

Answer (score 0):

Take care of what "this" is in what part of your function. In the innermost function, you are calling it from `$('#sandbox')`,which I suspect doesn't have a href attribute. the best solution would probably be to pass the value of the href into the function or store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.jNav').click(function()
            {
                $('#sandbox').load($(this).attr('href'),function() 
                {
                    alert("From here " + $(this).parent().attr('href') + " to here.");
                    loadScript();
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: `.jNav` might not actually be the parent of `#sandbox`.